# Download PSN games externally

Tags: psn, ps4

I have very slow internet at home which makes updating games a nightmare.

For example, a 2GB update for Destiny has recently come out, and since you have to be online to play the game I cannot play it again until I download this update. This will probably take a full day for me as I get about 200KB/s if it's behaving.

Is there a way to download the update (or full game) externally onto a USB Flash Drive and install onto the PS4?

By "externally" I simply mean, NOT on the PlayStation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly no. Would be very strange if possible. You can use your pc connection as proxy but doesn't seem to do any good. Take your ps4 to somewhere else I guess, like a friend's house, it's not that heavy. Or just wait a full day.